# How to send parameters in headers using http package in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to sent my auth-key in headers using http package but unfortunately its not working kindly help me .

```
var url = "https://paysafemoney.com/psmApi/Psm/userDashboard";


  var response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: {
      "auth-key": LoginConfirmActivity.authKey,
    },
    body: sendLoginData,
  );

  print("Response = ${response.body}");
```

Comment: check [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/authenticated-requests#add-authorization-headers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
var fullUrl = '$stripeBaseUrl$customerId/sources?source=$cardToken';
var header = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Authorization': stripeKey,
};
final response = await client.post(fullUrl, headers: header);
```

Comment: You can take the help from above example of stripe api